# How can I recover iCloud Calendar backup to iPhone 4?

Tags: icloud, iphone, backup, calendar

My calendar entries in my iPhone 4 have disappeared. I have no total backup - just calendar and contacts backup in iCloud. I only want to restore the calendar back to my iPhone 4. I already extracted the iCloud calendar backup into my PC.

Most websites only have instructions on how to restore the whole iCloud backup to the iPhone. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you previously synced your iPhone calendar with iCloud, you do not need to restore your iPhone. Just make sure you enable iCloud calendar sync by going to Settings → iCloud → Calendars → ON.

[image]

Always make sure [to keep a safe backup of iPhone calendars](http://www.copytrans.net/support/backup-iphone-calendar-computer/) and other data too in case you need to restore it later.